# Обязательно ли тире в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Тренер - игрокам: "Соберитесь: сегодня важный матч".

Необходимо ли тире в этом предложении? Я знаю, что постановка тире обусловлена отсутствием сказуемого между словами тренер и игрокам. Отсутствие тире будет считаться ошибкой?

Comment: Смотря где и кто будет проверять. В тестах будет, в диктанте - негрубая ошибка, могут и не засчитать.

Comment: А в художественной литературе автор может позволить себе не ставить тире в подобной ситуации?

Comment: Интересно,  в каком тексте можно найти такое предложение. На оформление пьесы похоже. Тренер игрокам. Соберитесь: сегодня важный матч.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Тренер — игрокам: "Соберитесь: сегодня важный матч"*.
>
> Отсутствие тире будет считаться ошибкой?

По-моему, непостановка тире в этом предложении не должна считаться ошибкой. Если предложение произносится без паузы после слова *тренер*, то и тире не нужно.

К примеру, в таком контексте:

*Тренер игрокам: "Соберитесь: сегодня важный матч". А они в ответ...*

В [**ПАС**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=107#pp107) говорится так:

> **§ 16.**  В неполных предложениях на месте пропущенных членов предложения
>   или их частей ставится тире...
>
> 2. В простом предложении с пропущенным сказуемым, указывающим на направление движения: *Татьяна — в лес, медведь — за нею* (П.).

В то же время там же:

> Примечание. Тире **может отсутствовать** при меньшей интонационной
>   расчлененности предложения:
>
> *Со второго слова **она мне**: «А есть ли, батюшка, деревеньки?»* (Дост.)

Ну а какова должна быть интонация при прочтении — это уже определяет пишущий.